# Generating parentheses using DFS

Tags: performance, algorithm, c

> I am solving the "Generating Parentheses Given a Number" challenge. The total number of parentheses combination turns out to be Catalan Series. The following code works but I am looking for comment on the coding style and performance. The particular solution itself might not be the most efficient but I want to try this algorithm out. In this code, I don't assume I know that this is Catalan Series, which might help with memory allocation a bit. The resizing could be more efficient and could have used `realloc`.

I have included the code without the reallocation for comparison. The solution using catalan passes the test. I am not trying to pass the test with this code. Just want some comment for my own improvement. This seems to be a popular problem online. Here is  question and article from leetcode. https://leetcode.com/articles/generate-parentheses/

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct paren_info_s{
    int     size;
    int     capacity;
    int     slen;
    char  **parens;
    int     idx;
} paren_info_t;

#define SIZE_INCREMENT 8

int catalan(int n)
{
    if (n <= 1 ) return 1;

    int res = 0;
    for (int i=0; i < n; i++) {
        res += catalan(i) *catalan(n-i-1);
    }
    return res;
}

void dfs_paren(int left, int right, paren_info_t *paren_info, char *temp)
{
    if (right < left) {
        return;
    }
#if 0
if (!left && !right) {
    paren_info->parens[paren_info->size] = malloc(sizeof(paren_info->slen));
    memcpy(paren_info->parens[paren_info->size], temp, paren_info->slen);
    paren_info->size++;
}
#endif
    if (!left && !right) {
        paren_info->parens[paren_info->size] = malloc(sizeof(paren_info->slen));
        memcpy(paren_info->parens[paren_info->size], temp, paren_info->slen);
        printf("%d. %s\n", paren_info->size, paren_info->parens[paren_info->size]);
        paren_info->size++;
        //memset(temp+paren_info->idx,0,paren_info->slen);
        if (paren_info->size >= paren_info->capacity) {
            char **temp_paren_info;
            paren_info->capacity = SIZE_INCREMENT * ((paren_info->size/2)+1);

            temp_paren_info = malloc(sizeof(char*)*(paren_info->capacity));
            for (int i=0; i < paren_info->size; i++) {
                temp_paren_info[i] = paren_info->parens[i];
            }
            free(paren_info->parens);
            paren_info->parens = temp_paren_info;
        }
    }
    int idx ;
    if (left>0) {
        idx = paren_info->idx;
        temp[paren_info->idx] = '(';
        paren_info->idx++;
        dfs_paren(left-1, right, paren_info, temp);
        temp[idx] = ' ';
        paren_info->idx--;

    }
    if (right>0) {
        idx = paren_info->idx;
        temp[paren_info->idx] = ')';
        paren_info->idx++;
        dfs_paren(left, right-1, paren_info, temp);
        temp[idx] = ' ';
        paren_info->idx--;
    }
}

char** gen_paren(int n, int* return_size, paren_info_t *paren_info)
{

    paren_info->size = 0;
    paren_info->parens = malloc(sizeof(char*)*SIZE_INCREMENT);
    paren_info->capacity= SIZE_INCREMENT;
    paren_info->slen = (n*2) + 1;
    paren_info->idx = 0;

    char *temp = malloc(paren_info->slen);
    memset(temp,0,paren_info->slen);
    dfs_paren(n,n,paren_info,temp);
    char **ans = malloc(sizeof(char*)*paren_info->size);
    for(int i=0; i < paren_info->size;i++) {
        ans[i] = paren_info->parens[i];
    }
    *return_size = paren_info->size;

    return ans;
}

void test_paren(int n)
{
    char** ans;
    int size;

    paren_info_t *paren_info;
    paren_info = malloc(sizeof(paren_info_t));

    ans = gen_paren(n, &size, paren_info);
    for(int i=0; i < size; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", ans[i]);
    }
}

int main() {
    test_paren(7);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please add a *description* of the task (and a link to the source if this comes from some online challenge/competition).

Comment: @wispymisty it appears that you have an unregistered account as well as a registered account (i.e. [wispymisty](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/175561/wispymisty))... bearing in mind this may have already been mentioned, you can use the [Contact](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/contact) link at the bottom of the page to request the accounts be merged.

Answer (score 2):

General recommendations:

1. Style: Please be consistent, you sometimes add spaces around operators, sometimes not, you sometimes add spaces after keywords, sometimes not, ...
2. Comments ...
3. Choose appropriate types, almost all `int`s here would be better as `size_t` as they describe the size of an object or things related to such.
4. Make compilation-unit local functions `static`.
5. An empty parameter-list does *never* constitute a function prototype, thus calling said function with different parameters does not constitute a compilation error:

   ```
   int foo() {} // no prototype!
   int main(void) // prototype!
   {
       foo(6); // no compilation error!
       main(6); // compilation error!
   }
   ```
6. Your code isn't C89 compatible anyway, only declare variables as you need them, this makes it easier to keep the types in mind, etc.
7. Make things `const`, if possible
8. `free()` allocated memory
9. When using `malloc()`, don't encode the type like `sizeof (char)` but rather use `sizeof(temp[0])` -- maybe at some point the type changes and then your code would be wrong. This is part of the DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) principle.

Code-specific:

- Line 102: You allocate memory for `paren_info` although this variable is only used in `gen_parens()` and its subfunctions. Just remove that parameter and allocate it in `gen_parens()` on the stack.
- Line 79: Following from that, use a structured initializer to initalize the `struct` (cf. code attached).
- Line 88: You copy all the data from `paren_info->parens` to `ans`. Why? Just return `paren_info->parens` and be happy!
- Line 38: The base case is quite long and boring, the actual recursion before. I think it makes sense to just inverse the condition and put this case at the end (you can remove one indention then, too, if you put a return after the other blocks)
- Line 57 & 66: Mostly the same code, completely not-DRY. Put it into the same scope and move the `if`s inside.
- Line 39: It's not `sizeof (paren_info->size)` but just `paren_info->size`.
- Line 49: If you don't use `realloc()` at least use `memcpy()`.
- Line 76: Why do you make the size an "out"-Paremeter and just not return it directly and return the answer via a passed pointer?

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>

typedef struct paren_info_s {
    size_t  size;           // number of combinations written, ie. full entries in parens
    size_t  capacity;       // number of slots in parens, ie. total entries in parens
    size_t  slen;           // length of each entry in parens, ie. 2*n +1 ('\0'-Byte)
    char  **parens;         // parens[size][slen]
    size_t  idx;            // current index for writing '('/')'
} paren_info_t;

#define SIZE_INCREMENT 8

#if 0
static int catalan(int n)
{
    if (n <= 1 ) return 1;

    int res = 0;
    for (int i=0; i < n; i++) {
        res += catalan(i) *catalan(n-i-1);
    }
    return res;
}
#endif

static void dfs_paren(const unsigned int left, const unsigned int right,
        paren_info_t *const paren_info, char *const temp)
{
    if (right < left) {
        return;
    }


    if (left > 0 || right > 0) {
        // recursive call
        const size_t idx = paren_info->idx;

        paren_info->idx++;
        if (left > 0) {
            temp[idx] = '(';
            dfs_paren(left-1, right, paren_info, temp);
        }
        if (right > 0) {
            temp[idx] = ')';
            dfs_paren(left, right-1, paren_info, temp);
        }
        paren_info->idx--;

        return;
    }

    // recursion base case: left == right == 0
    assert(paren_info->size <= paren_info->capacity);

    // resize the array
    if (paren_info->size >= paren_info->capacity) {
        paren_info->capacity = SIZE_INCREMENT * ((paren_info->size/2)+1);
        char **const temp_paren_info = malloc(sizeof (temp_paren_info[0]) * (paren_info->capacity));

        memcpy(temp_paren_info, paren_info->parens, sizeof (temp_paren_info[0]) * paren_info->size);

        free(paren_info->parens);
        paren_info->parens = temp_paren_info;
    }

    // write the final temp array into paren_info struct
    paren_info->parens[paren_info->size] = malloc(paren_info->slen);
    memcpy(paren_info->parens[paren_info->size], temp, paren_info->slen);
    paren_info->size++;
}

static size_t gen_paren(const unsigned int n, char ***const result)
{
    paren_info_t paren_info = {
        .size = 0,
        .parens = malloc(sizeof (paren_info.parens[0]) * SIZE_INCREMENT),
        .capacity = SIZE_INCREMENT,
        .slen = (n*2) +1,
        .idx = 0,
    };

    char *const temp = malloc(paren_info.slen);
    temp[paren_info.slen-1] = '\0';
    dfs_paren(n, n, &paren_info, temp);
    free(temp);

    *result = paren_info.parens;
    return paren_info.size;
}

static void test_paren(const unsigned int n)
{
    char **ans;
    const size_t size = gen_paren(n, &ans);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", ans[i]);
        free(ans[i]);
    }

    free(ans);
}

int main(void) {
    test_paren(7);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the posted code does NOT cleanly compile!

The following is the result of compiling with `gcc`.

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11  -ggdb -c "untitled.c" 

untitled.c: In function ‘dfs_paren’:

untitled.c:40:60: warning: conversion to ‘size_t {aka long unsigned int}’ from ‘int’ may change the sign of the result [-Wsign-conversion]
     memcpy(paren_info->parens[paren_info->size], temp, paren_info->slen);
                                                        ^~~~~~~~~~

untitled.c:48:51: warning: conversion to ‘long unsigned int’ from ‘int’ may change the sign of the result [-Wsign-conversion]
         temp_paren_info = malloc(sizeof(char*)*(paren_info->capacity));
                                               ^

untitled.c: In function ‘gen_paren’:

untitled.c:85:25: warning: conversion to ‘size_t {aka long unsigned int}’ from ‘int’ may change the sign of the result [-Wsign-conversion]
 char *temp = malloc(paren_info->slen);
                     ^~~~~~~~~~

untitled.c:86:19: warning: conversion to ‘size_t {aka long unsigned int}’ from ‘int’ may change the sign of the result [-Wsign-conversion]
 memset(temp,0,paren_info->slen);
               ^~~~~~~~~~

untitled.c:88:38: warning: conversion to ‘long unsigned int’ from ‘int’ may change the sign of the result [-Wsign-conversion]
 char **ans = malloc(sizeof(char*)*paren_info->size);
                                  ^
```

The use of appropriate horizontal spacing inside parens, after commas, inside brackets, inside braces, after semicolons, and around C operators would make the code more readable and more easily understood.

Separating code blocks `for` `if` `else` `while` `do...while` `switch` `case` `default` by a single blank line would make the code much more readable and understandable

separating functions by 2 or 3 blank lines (be consistent) would make the code much more readable and understandable

the parameter to `malloc()` should be a `size_t`, not an `int`

it is best to separate the definition of a struct from a `typedef` for that struct

when calling any of the heap allocation functions: `malloc` `calloc` `realloc`, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful

honor the right page boundary (either column 72 or column 80)  so the code can be easily printed

the posted code has many memory leaks, as it does not pass the `malloc`d pointers to `free()`

regarding: `int main()`   This is telling the compiler that the `main` function can have any number of parameters.  Not quite what you want.  Suggest: `int main( void )`